# I can't run php on my vps: Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, apache, server, vps, internal

I am using hostnine vps. When I set up domain and upload file I notice that php code gives "Internal Server Error". But html run without problem.

**In cpanel server errors show this error:**

> [Sun Dec 04 21:06:10 2016] [error] [client 188.139.123.21] File does
>   not exist: /home/myusername/public_html/500.shtml [Sun Dec 04
>   21:06:10 2016] [error] [client 188.139.123.21] SoftException in
>   Application.cpp:608: Directory "/home/myusername/public_html" is
>   writeable by group

**browser gives me this error:**

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@nysite.org and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: `chmod 755 /home/myusername/public_html`

Comment: tried but not work :(

Comment: find your [php error log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel)

Comment: i cann't find it.

Comment: you **must** find it.  for instance, if i were to drive a car, and the police kept pulling me over because i had no speedometer, they would take away my license.  if you continue to code php without your error log, someone is going to take your coding license away from you.

Comment: Removed some unneeded text.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution what I get was, full backup and it works fine now.